# How to sum column value or multiple values in multi-dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays

How can I add all the columnar values by associative key? Note that key sets are dynamic and some key value is more than one.

Example array :

```
$myArray = array(
    ["apple" => 2,"orange" => 1,"lemon" => 4,"grape" => 5],
    ["apple" => 5,"orange" => 0,"lemon" => 3,"grape" => 2],
    ["apple" => 3,"orange" => 0,"lemon" => 1,"grape" => 3],
);
```

With single key value I can sum the column value easily with the code below.

```
$sumArray = array();

foreach ($myArray as $k => $subArray) 
{
  foreach ($subArray as $id => $value) 
  {
    if (array_key_exists($id, $sumArray)) 
    {
        $sumArray[$id] += $value;
    } else {
        $sumArray[$id] = $value;
    }
  }
}
echo json_encode($sumArray);
```

the result will be like these:

```
{"apple":10,"orange":1,"lemon":8,"grape":10}
```

For multiple key values the code above is not working. How to sum column values if key value is more than one?

Example array:

```
$myArraymulti = array(
   ["apple" => 2,"orange" => 1,"lemon" => [4, 2],"grape" => 5],
   ["apple" => 5,"orange" => [0, 2],"lemon" => 3,"grape" => 2],
   ["apple" => 3,"orange" => 0,"lemon" => 1,"grape" => [3, 8]],
);
```

Desired result:

```
{"apple":10,"orange":3,"lemon":10,"grape":18}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if the value is an array. If it is, use the sum of the elements instead of the value itself when adding to the associative array.

```
foreach ($myArray as $k => $subArray) 
{
  foreach ($subArray as $id => $value) 
  {
    if (is_array($value)) {
      $value_to_add = array_sum($value);
    } else {
      $value_to_add = $value;
    }
    if (array_key_exists($id, $sumArray)) 
    {
        $sumArray[$id] += $value_to_add;
    } else {
        $sumArray[$id] = $value_to_add;
    }
  }
}
```

I suggest you fix your data structure, though. You should just make every value an array, rather than mixing singletons and arrays, so you don't have to use conditionals in all the code that processes the data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your code it is working. Awesome man!

Answer (score 0):

```
$keys = [];
forEach($myArraymulti as $array){    
    $keys =  array_merge(array_keys($array), $keys);
}
$res = [];
forEach(array_unique($keys) as $key){
    forEach($myArraymulti as $array){
        if(isset($array[$key])){
            $res[$key] =    (isset($res[$key]) ? $res[$key] : 0) + 
                            (is_array($array[$key]) ? array_sum($array[$key]) : $array[$key]); 
        }
    }
}
$res = json_encode($res));
```